# What Does $_session['error'] means in php

Tags: php

I have this php code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
echo "<span id='error'><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";
unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

What Does $_SESSION['error'] means
and unset one please explain

Comment: Hi! Have you tried googling? http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SESSION contains all session variables (user ID of logged in user for example). You can set a session variable like this:

`$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';`

And access it later (after multiple page loads still, that's why it's so useful) using:

```
$foo = $_SESSION['foo'];
echo $foo; //Displays 'bar'
```

Your code checks if there is a session variable set, and if so display an error and unset the session variable. So I would guess this is to show a one-time error when something went wrong. Using a session variable means you can execute this code on a different page then where the error happened.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['error']` means a an array key of `$_SESSION` which was generated by you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks in the session, which is a temporary storage that is unique to the user and more often than not is mean to last for the time a user stays on a page in a single *"visit session"*, for a variable (actually rather an [array key](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) called `error`; it then injects whatever that contains (likely an error message) into a piece of HTML, and after that, it deletes the error from the session storage with [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Take a look on the documentation for [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).